# How to limit a Toplevel's position in Tkinter

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I have a python program which has a button to popup a Toplevel windows in the center.

I can use `Toplevel.resizable(0, 0)` to limit the size of window, but i want to limit the position of windows and can't move the window by mouse.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Toplevel.overrideredirect(True)` to make the Window Manager ignore this window. This removes the title bar and borders, thus preventing the user from moving it, but this also removes it from the taskbar.

Comment: is it no way to just block the movement event?  Toplevel.overrideredirect(True) makes the windows too ugly.